# Watching messages to an object in Xcode debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'd like to use gdb or Xcode's debugger to watch every message sent to an object in an Objective-C 2.0 program.  I don't care about arguments and such, as I just need to see every message it receives (retain, release, autorelease, etc).  I also don't want to profile my entire program.

Is there a means, in Xcode, to select an instance (possibly by address) and say "show me every message sent to this object"?  Since the plumbing is fairly standard, I imagine there would have to be a probe hook or something.  Anyone ever done this?

*(Aside from subclassing the object in question, of course; looking for a more general solution.)*

This is for iPhone development with Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the [NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled environment variable](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html) to YES and then grep/filter through the resulting log for the object you're interested in.

[Here's a relevant blog post](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/) as well, though I'm not sure how much of the information there is still true in the runtime today. (It might all be. I really don't know.)

Comment: That's a handy document for a lot of other things as well.  Thank you!